# In Azure Data Factory, "Copy" Activity, I can't see my SharePoint List entries in the "Sink" - list of datasets

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

My ADF Pipeline has datasets for SharePoint lists, which show up fine - in a Copy Activity - as data *Sources*, but do not appear as data *Sinks*

Further, if I try to create a new linked service "on the fly", the option to create a "SharePoint List Online" does not appear

The User is a member of the SharePoint site, although not an Owner, and I've granted write (edit) permission for the table concerned

How can I get permission to write to SharePoint?

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SharePoint Online List is not supported as a Sink in Copy Activity.

SharePoint Online List is supported as Source only.

[image]

Refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats)

Comment: Thanks; I've since found you can (manually) copy Excel to SL, which more or less answers our current need, but is there any (M/S) way of doing it programmatically?